# How do I add text last in a text element in html via js

Tags: javascript, html, text, innerhtml

I want to add text last in a p element, not first, but i only know how to add last using +=

```js
var pEL = document.querySelector("#text");
pEL.innerHTML += "1";
```

```html
<p id="text">text</p>
```

now the p element says "text1" but i want "1text", how do i add something first in a text element?

Comment: Basic string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

```
pE1.innerHTML += "1";
```

is simply shorthand for saying "the new html will be the old html + "1"

```
pEl.innerHTML = pEl.innerHTML + "1"
```

so instead, something like

```
pEL.innerHTML = "1" + pEl.innerHTML
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The Element property `innerHTML` gets or sets the HTML or XML markup contained within the element so set it with concatenating 1 + the previous text (calling `pEL.innerHTML` without assignment is basiclly using the get to fetch the value)

```js
var pEL = document.querySelector("#text");
pEL.innerHTML = "1" + pEL.innerHTML;
```

```html
<p id="text">text</p>
```